I need some turkey broth to keep my turkey leftovers from drying out. How can I make it so it doesn't become gelatinous stock?
I am cooking my Thanksgiving turkey the day before Thanksgiving.  I will be taking meat and all the usual trimmings to my parents Thanksgiving morning.  I would like to have some broth to store their meat in in the refrigerator to keep moisture in for the reheat.  I have tried several times to achieve this in the past and always end up with gelatin.  Is there anything I can do to prevent this?

Frame challenge: the gelatinous stock will get liquid again when reheated. Wouldn’t that suffice?

In my experience with it, the top of the meat will dry out before that happens.    Usually it isn't a big deal for me after Thanksgiving day, but since I am doing a day ahead for my parents, I really want to ensure the meat has good, flavorful moisture.

First, ensure that you turkey is not overcooked, which is the main reason that people experience dry turkey.  Then, when storing, cover in plastic wrap.  Put the plastic right on the surface of the meat, removing as much air as possible.  Finally, to answer you question more specifically, make a quick vegetable stock.  That way you don't introduce any collagen or gelatin into the system.  Save the turkey bones for a soup (you could even add the leftover vegetable stock).

This is right @Kim, adding moisture after the fact doesn't actually keep the meat moist, it's the moisture remaining in the turkey that needs to be moist, the key is not to overcook it, and to get it cooled and wrapped as soon as you can.

moscafj, I never would have thought to make a vegetable stock/broth.  Maybe I will pick some up.  I already have so much on my plate.

GdD, my turkey ALWAYS is very moist until it is reheated in the microwave.  I was looking for something I could add to the moist meat when storing it over night in the fridge to ensure it would be moist upon reheat.  The microwave reheat ALWAYS seems to dry it out to a certain extent, even when going on a lower power setting.  I wanted to make a turkey broth that would not turn gelatinous overnight.

@Kim heat up the broth (which would turn it back to liquid if it was homemade), then put meat slices into that to warm up, and you won't have issues with drying out.  You can also reheat it in the oven (with the dish wrapped with foil to keep moisture in).  Microwaving is possibly one of the worst ways to heat food and keep it from drying out, as the microwave will cause the water on the surfaces to heat fastest and possibly evaporate.
